# No enum constant org.apache.orc.Compression.zlib Hive2

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I have been working with Hadoop 2.7.7 and Hive 2.0 for the last 2 weeks.
I have created a table with ORC without any compression, Loaded the data from an external table pointing to the CSV.

I created a new ORC Table with codec zlib, but while loading the data from the previously created ORC table using the query `INSERT INTO TABLE orders_orc_zlib SELECT * FROM orders_orc;`

I'm facing the following issue

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"order_id":8796,"cust_id":"10000","order_date":null,"order_time":null,"freight_charges":33.99,"order_salesman":"SC124 ","order_posted_date":null,"order_ship_date":"05/08/09"}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"order_id":8796,"cust_id":"10000","order_date":null,"order_time":null,"freight_charges":33.99,"order_salesman":"SC124 ","order_posted_date":null,"order_ship_date":"05/08/09"}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.zlib
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:561)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.zlib
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:272)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketForFileIdx(FileSinkOperator.java:612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:556)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.zlib
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
        at org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.valueOf(CompressionKind.java:25)
        at org.apache.orc.OrcFile$WriterOptions.<init>(OrcFile.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile$WriterOptions.<init>(OrcFile.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.writerOptions(OrcFile.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat.getOptions(OrcOutputFormat.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat.getHiveRecordWriter(OrcOutputFormat.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat.getHiveRecordWriter(OrcOutputFormat.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:269)
        ... 18 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

The data shown in the error is the first row when I query the table
I have googled this issue but found that this issue was there for `Lz4` codec and couldn't find anything on `zlib`

PS:- `Snappy` is working fine and I need the data file in `ORC zlib`